# windows command shell script

Tags: windows, command-line

This is a question regarding CMD shell script, I have seen a script as below:

```
FOR %%X in (java.exe javac.exe ant.bat android.bat) do (
    SET FOUND=%%~$PATH:X
    IF NOT DEFINED %FOUND% GOTO MISSING
)
```

Can any one explain to me what is `%%~$PATH:X` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%~$PATH:X` is path concatenation.

`%%X` is the name of  the instance variable, which is set to `java.exe`, `javac.exe`, etc. as it iterates through the `FOR` loop

The `~$PATH:` between `%%` and `X` is basically searching for a file named `java.exe` (or whatever `%%X` is set to at the moment) in every directory contained within the `%PATH%` environment variable.

Also, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781795/420156) which reiterates the technique and contains some discussion about it (but doesn't explain in theoretical terms what it syntactically does). There's a good discussion about `PATHEXT` there, too.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how *exactly* `%%~$PATH:X` works? I know how `%PATH:windows=win%` (substitution) and `%PATH:~0,20%` (substring extraction) for example work, but what is FOUND being set to here? I see that it is checking whether FOUND is DEFINED or not, not whether it EXISTs or not, so what's really happening?

Answer (score 2):

Each directory in PATH environment variable is scanned for existence of file %X, and the name of the first matching directory is saved into FOUND.

Type `HELP FOR` in the windows CMD shell to get full docs.